# Delegate installation of a subproject with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I'm having trouble to figure out how to **delegate** the installation of a subproject with Ansible.

Here is my situation

I maintain 2 projects, one of them is used by the other. Let's call them:

```
- Project_parent
- Project_child
```

I already wrote an installation playbook for Project_child, which now lives in the git repository.

```
Project_child/deploy/
- site.yml
- roles/
   - role_A
   - role_B
   - role_C
```

My goal is to write a playbook for the Project_parent, and delegate the Project_child's installation to the **child's itself** (since I already wrote the playbook)

## Solution 1 - import_playbook

Write Project_parent's playbook, and import the child's playbook to delegate the installation.

Problem: you can only call import_playbook from the top-level, so this doesn't work:

```yaml
Project_parent/deploy
- site.yml
- roles/
  - Project_child/tasks/main.yml -> git clone && import_playbook here # doesnt' work
```

So this doesn't work.

## Solution 2 - Ansible collections

The idea is to package Project_child's roles into a collection, and reuse it in Project_parent.

```
Project_parent/deploy
- site.yml
- roles/
  - namespace.collection.role_A
  - namespace.collection.role_B
  - namespace.collection.role_C
  - roleD
  - roleE
...
```

--> The issue I have with this approach is that we have **tighly coupled** the parent's playbook with the child's role set.

If the child's role set changes (add, remove, rename), the parent playbook **must be updated as well**.

So this isn't the "installation delegation" I would expect.

I would like an equivalent of **"make -C Project_child" for Ansible**.

Is there anything I am missing to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Add  the path to `Project_child/deploy/roles` to [DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-roles-path) after you clone Project_child.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your comment @VladimirBotka, I don't understand how it solves the issue of coupling and delegation ?
Thanks.